# Complex number class

Tags: java, c++, python

I have an assignment due but I'm having trouble understanding what the assignment is really asking me to do, or how to go about it. I know what complex numbers are but I don't understand what the following operations for the C++ and Python version are supposed to do:

```
op: Complex × Complex → Complex 
op: Complex × double → Complex 
op: double × Complex → Complex
```

double? I'm not understanding where double comes into this. Also the python version should convert complexes into strings, again I don't understand what it is asking. Is it saying to literally convert complexes(integers?) to a string data type? Please let me know if you can try to help me understand just what the assignment is asking so I can try to program it.

> Complex number class
>
> Design a class in C++, Java, and Python that represents complex
>   numbers and supports important operations such as addition,
>   subtraction, multiplication and division. For the C++ and Python
>   versions you will need to implement the following functions for each
>   operation:
>
> ```
> op: Complex × Complex → Complex
> op: Complex × double → Complex  op:
> double × Complex → Complex
> ```
>
> Where op is one of +, -, *, or /. In
>   addition, you will need to overload the stream insertion operator <<
>   to print objects of this type.  A constructor must be defined as well
>   as overloading the assignment operator to allow for implicit
>   conversion from doubles to Complex. Any other methods you deem
>   appropriate should also be included. The more complete your class the
>   better.
>
> The Java version will not have as many methods because Java does not
>   allow for operator overloading or friend functions. Again, the more
>   complete your Java class the better. Override the toString() method.
>
> The Python version you should also include functions for converting
>   from complexes to strings.
>
> The required files for this project are: a complex.h file that
>   contains the declaration of the complex class, a complex.cc file that
>   contains the implementations of method and functions declared in the
>   complex class, a main.cc that instantiates complex numbers and tests
>   all methods and functions, a Complex.java file that is the Java
>   implementation, and a Main.java file that instantiates and tests all
>   methods of the Complex class. The python files required are a
>   complex.py file.

He provided us with the following code:

```
/*
 *
 *  Java version
 *
 */

/* Main.java */

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Rational a = new Rational(1, 2);
        Rational b = new Rational(2, 3);

        int i = 5;

        System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " = " + a.add(b));
        System.out.println(a + " - " + b + " = " + a.sub(b));
        System.out.println(a + " * " + b + " = " + a.mul(b));
        System.out.println(a + " / " + b + " = " + a.div(b));

        System.out.println(a + " + " + i + " = " + a.add(i));
        System.out.println(a + " - " + i + " = " + a.sub(i));
        System.out.println(a + " * " + i + " = " + a.mul(i));
        System.out.println(a + " / " + i + " = " + a.div(i));
    }
}

/* Rational.java */

public class Rational {

    public Rational() {

        this(0);
    }

    public Rational(int num) {

        this(num, 1);
    }

    public Rational(int num, int den) {

        this.num = num;
        this.den = den;
    }

    public Rational add(Rational o) {

        return new Rational(num * o.den + o.num * den, den * o.den);
    }

    public Rational add(int n) {

        return new Rational(num + n * den, den);
    }

    public Rational div(Rational o) {

        return new Rational(num * o.den, den * o.num);
    }

    public Rational div(int n) {

        return new Rational(num, den * n);
    }

    public Rational mul(Rational o) {

        return new Rational(num * o.num, den * o.den);
    }

    public Rational mul(int n) {

        return new Rational(num * n, den);
    }

    public Rational sub(Rational o) {

        return new Rational(num * o.den - o.num * den, den * o.den);
    }

    public Rational sub(int n) {

        return new Rational(num - n * den, den);
    }

    public String toString() {

        return "(" + num + " / " + den + ")";
    }

    private int den;
    private int num;
}

/*
 *
 *  C++ version
 *
 */

/* rational.h */

#ifndef RATIONAL_H
#define RATIONAL_H

#include <iostream>

using std::ostream;

struct rational {

    rational(int = 0, int = 1);

    rational operator+(const rational &) const;
    rational operator-(const rational &) const;
    rational operator*(const rational &) const;
    rational operator/(const rational &) const;

    rational operator+(int) const;
    rational operator-(int) const;
    rational operator*(int) const;
    rational operator/(int) const;

    friend rational operator+(int, const rational &);
    friend rational operator-(int, const rational &);
    friend rational operator*(int, const rational &);
    friend rational operator/(int, const rational &);

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const rational &);

private:

    int den;
    int num;
};

#endif /* RATIONAL_H */

/* rational.cc */

#include <iostream>
#include "rational.h"

rational::rational(int num, int den) : num(num), den(den) {}

rational rational::operator+(const rational &o) const {

    return rational(num * o.den + o.num * den, den * o.den);
}

rational rational::operator+(int n) const {

    return rational(num + n * den, den);
}

rational rational::operator-(const rational &o) const {

    return rational(num * o.den - o.num * den, den * o.den);
}

rational rational::operator-(int n) const {

    return rational(num - n * den, den);
}

rational rational::operator*(const rational &o) const {

    return rational(num * o.num, den * o.den);
}

rational rational::operator*(int n) const {

    return rational(num * n, den);
}

rational rational::operator/(const rational &o) const {

    return rational(num * o.den, den * o.num);
}

rational rational::operator/(int n) const {

    return rational(num, den * n);
}

rational operator+(int n, const rational &o) {

    return o + n;
}

rational operator-(int n, const rational &o) {

    return rational(n) - o;
}

rational operator*(int n, const rational &o) {

    return o * n;
}

rational operator/(int n, const rational &o) {

    return rational(n) / o;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const rational &o) {

    out << '(' << o.num << " / " << o.den << ')';
    return out;
}

/* main.cc */

#include <iostream>
#include "rational.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(void) {

    rational a(1, 2);
    rational b(2, 3);

    int i = 5;

    cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << a + b << endl;
    cout << a << " - " << b << " = " << a - b << endl;
    cout << a << " * " << b << " = " << a * b << endl;
    cout << a << " / " << b << " = " << a / b << endl;

    cout << a << " + " << i << " = " << a + i << endl;
    cout << a << " - " << i << " = " << a - i << endl;
    cout << a << " * " << i << " = " << a * i << endl;
    cout << a << " / " << i << " = " << a / i << endl;

    cout << i << " + " << a << " = " << i + a << endl;
    cout << i << " - " << a << " = " << i - a << endl;
    cout << i << " * " << a << " = " << i * a << endl;
    cout << i << " / " << a << " = " << i / a << endl;

    return 0;
}

#
#
# Python version
#
#

class rational:
    def __init__(self, num=0, den=1):
        self.num = num
        self.den = den

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return rational(self.num + other * self.den, self.den)
        elif isinstance(other, rational):
            return rational(self.num * other.den + other.num * self.den, self.den * other.den)
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return rational(self.num, self.den * other)
        elif isinstance(other, rational):
            return rational(self.num * other.den, self.den * other.num)
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.num) / self.den

    def __int__(self):
        return self.num / self.den

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return rational(self.num * other, self.den)
        elif isinstance(other, rational):
            return rational(self.num * other.num, self.den * other.den)
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self + other

    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        return rational(other) / self

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self * other

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return rational(other) - self

    def __str__(self):
        return '(' + str(self.num) + ' / ' + str(self.den) + ')'

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return rational(self.num - other * self.den, self.den)
        elif isinstance(other, rational):
            return rational(self.num * other.den - other.num * self.den, self.den * other.den)
        else:
            raise TypeError

if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = rational(1, 2)
    b = rational(2, 3)

    i = 5

    print('%s + %s = %s' % (a, b, a + b))
    print('%s - %s = %s' % (a, b, a - b))
    print('%s * %s = %s' % (a, b, a * b))
    print('%s / %s = %s' % (a, b, a / b))

    print('%s + %i = %s' % (a, i, a + i))
    print('%s - %i = %s' % (a, i, a - i))
    print('%s * %i = %s' % (a, i, a * i))
    print('%s / %i = %s' % (a, i, a / i))

    print('%i + %s = %s' % (i, a, i + a))
    print('%i - %s = %s' % (i, a, i - a))
    print('%i * %s = %s' % (i, a, i * a))
    print('%i / %s = %s' % (i, a, i / a))
```

Comment: Do you understand complex numbers well enough to know how these operations work? A `double` is a type of real number in `c++`, so are probably intended to use it to store the real and imaginary parts of your complex number. You probably need to read up on [operator overloading](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html). Do you really have to write 3 different versions of this (in 3 different languages)?

Comment: I think you made a confusion between fraction `q / r` and complex numbers `a + bi`

Comment: I think you need to pick a language, because the answers in each will be significantly different.

Comment: I need to write it in all 3 : [

Comment: which is it? do you want to implement complex numbers or rational numbers?

Comment: Code you received is for a class to represent Rational numbers. You need to rewrite the same kinds of classes to represent Complex numbers. It should be helping you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion to string is just to display the number in a human readable form. That is in the rational class: `return "(" + num + " / " + den + ")";` prints for instance `(5 / 8)`. Your complex class could make the toString method to output `( 5 + 8i )`

Multiplying a complex by a number (double) is a valid operation which gives another complex as result.

Multiplying a complex number by a real number:

```
(x + yi) u = xu + yu i.
```

With the code he gave, you have the exact same assignment completed for a Rational number (defined as two numbers num and den). You need to adapt that code to complex numbers which are also defined as a couple of numbers.

PS hint: http://www.clarku.edu/~djoyce/complex/mult.html

Comment: So the assignment is asking for the java version to only work with complex operations and for the C++/python to work with operations that involves not only complex but also both complex and real number(double)?

Comment: You can do it with all languages, in Java it would look like: `public Complex mul(double u) { ... }`.

Comment: Still having trouble understanding what the question is asking by 

op: Complex × Complex → Complex
op: Complex × double → Complex  
op: double × Complex → Complex

Comment: for the C++ and python version. Is the set up of the code I provided how the operations should be? Also it says that "you will need to overload the stream insertion operator << to print objects of this type. A constructor must be defined as well as overloading the assignment operator to allow for implicit conversion from doubles to Complex". Isn't that already provided in the code for the rational program?  friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const rational &);

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not understanding where double comes into this.

I would assume it's a plain `double` floating point value instead of a Complex value.

> Also the python version should convert complexes into strings, again I don't understand what it is asking.

I assume, use a String instead of a custom class called Complex.

> Is it saying to literally convert complexes(integers?) to a string data type?

I would assume so unless you know otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A complex number contains a real and an imaginary part, both stored as doubles. Since you say you know about these already I won't go into any detail, but a quick google reveals many Java implementations of the complex number class you are almost after.

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/Complex.java.html

Is an example which I have used before, and it fits what you are asking for:

```
public Complex times(Complex b)
public Complex times(double alpha)
```

These methods will take a complex number, or an alpha to apply to the real and imaginary parts, and return a complex number.

As for the python string part, I think he wants you to take the real and imaginary parts, and express them in some human readable form: a string

Hope I helped
md_5

Answer (score 0):

When the assignement says

> op: Complex × Complex → Complex
>   op: Complex × double → Complex  op:
>   double × Complex → Complex
>   Where op is one of +, -, *, or /.

it means that you must implement all binary operations between couples of Complex number and also between mixed couples of Real and Complex. For example for

*: Complex × double → Complex

you should write something like:

```
Complex operator*(Complex z, double t) {
  return Complex(t * z.Real(), t * z.Imag()); 
}
```